# Extracting RColorBrewer palette for other use

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using RColorBrewer (palette = "Set2"). I would like to extract the list of colors and use them for annotations. Is there a way to extract a vector of Set2 colors (call it List) and use that to make an annotation match the color already in use (color=List(3))?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can extract the colors like this

```
library(RColorBrewer)
f <- function(pal) brewer.pal(brewer.pal.info[pal, "maxcolors"], pal)
(cols <- f("Set1"))
# [1] "#E41A1C" "#377EB8" "#4DAF4A" "#984EA3" "#FF7F00" "#FFFF33" "#A65628" "#F781BF" "#999999"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have put this into the software and it works. I don't suppose you have a source for answering ColorBrewer questions like this? I could not find a solution after searching for an hour or two.

Comment: It's all in the help - just type `?RColorBrewer`.